# How to Resolve this GNOME Shell Extension (gTile) Problem?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I installed the GNOME extension gTile but GNOME Tweaks has the button for this extension greyed out and a triangular alert sign beside it.

When I try to launch the extension I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: redeclaration of formal parameter iter

Stack trace:
Application<._getExtensionPrefsModule@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:75:13
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Application<._selectExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:90:31
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Application<._onCommandLine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:246:17
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
main@resource:///org/gnome/shell/extensionPrefs/main.js:402:5
@<main>:1:43
```

Any idea of what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the extension is not (officially) supported for GNOME shell v3.26 (yet).

You may try the following (*no guarantee it will work*):

1. Go to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and look for the folder corresponding to *gTile*. Open the folder.
2. Open the `metadata.json` file.
3. Add `"3.26"` under `"shell-version":` (follow the way other version numbers are added).

You may also consider some alternatives, for example:

- [zTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1298/ztile/)
- [Tilingnome](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1286/tilingnome/)
- [shellshape](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/294/shellshape/)
- [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)

Comment: Thanks, is there something specifically in the error that allows you to know it's not supported? I don't know how to read the error.

Comment: @JamesHill You can also visit their site and see in the details.